# how to merge two array to model array?

Tags: swift

for example. I have two array

```
let array1 = ["one","two","three"]
let array2 = ["one","two","three"]
```

my datamodel is

```
struct datamodel: Hashable{
        var image:String
        var name:String
}
```

how can I merge two arrays into the model array

```
dataarray = [datamodel(image:array1[0],name:array2[0])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first array contains values for `image` and the second values for `name`?

You could iterate through them both at the same time and map those values to  the model (let's call it `DataModel` to be a bit Swiftier). You could only have as many results as the the count of the smaller of the two arrays, so you could try:

```swift
let dataArray = (0..<min(array1.count, array2.count))
    .map { DataModel(image: array1[$0], name: array2[$0]) }
```

Put a little more verbosely:

```swift
let minCount = min(array1.count, array2.count)

let dataArray = (0..<minCount).map { index in
    DataModel(image: array1[index], name: array2[index]) 
}
```

Comment: This is just reimplementing `zip`.

Comment: @Jessy except it crashes when the shorter of the two arrays reaches its end

Comment: Yep, zip is better. Good catch! Zip should use the shorter of the two just as this does.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` to merge the two arrays into an array of tuples and `map` to map the tuple to your type

```
let models = zip(array1, array2).map(DataModel.init)
```

Comment: You could even simply write `.map ( DataModel.init )`.

Comment: @vadian thanks a lot. I didn’t even consider that since the input was a tuple, I learned something new now.