# map inside map error? move the index outside

Tags: swift

for example. I have two array for DataModel

```
let array1 = ["one","two","three"]
let array2 = ["one","two","three"]
```

another two array for DataModel2

```
let array3 = ["one","two","three"]
let array4 = ["one","two","three"]
```

my DataModel is

```
struct DataModel: Hashable{
        var image:String
        var name:String
        var dataModel2:[DataModel2]
}
struct DataModel2: Hashable{
        var image2:String
        var name2:String
}
```

I use the map method

```
convermodel = (0..<array2.count).map{
            index1 in
            datamodel(DataModel(image: array1[index], name: array2[index]) 
, dataModel2: (0..<array3.count).map{ index2 in
            DataModel2(image: array1[index2], name: array2[index2]) 
            
        }}
```

the compliyer call "Expected expression in list of expressions" " try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

so how can i move index2 to the outside ??

Comment: What's the expected result? Could you show it? It's unclear how you want to "mix array3 & array4" with array1 & array2... All the "one" together, two together"? Because `dataModel2` is an array, so it's unclear.

Comment: Have you tried the other (and more efficient) suggestion in your previous question?

Comment: @vadian
i try it before, but it no solve my problem.because i have parent and child model, i try to map the parent datamodel,and child datamodel , it ,s no work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Joakim Danielson's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69951949/how-to-merge-two-array-to-model-array/69952478#69952478) answer in your previous question you can do it without any loop by `zip`ping the arrays

```
let converModel = zip(array3, array4)
    .map{ DataModel(image: $0.0, name: $0.1, dataModel2: zip(array1, array2).map(DataModel2.init)) }
```